# Preview crashes on Print command

Tags: macos, preview, printing, crash, textedit

I have this crash on Preview and TextEdit happening every time I use the Print command. cmd+p = spinning ball... It's only on these two apps, as far as I know. Ie: Mail app prints fine. Both MS Office and Acrobat Reader print okay.

Printed installed: Canon MF4360-4390 using driver Canon MF4360-4390 UFRII LT (UK); version 2.0

Current OS: 10.7.2

On 10.6 it worked fine.
I already deleted the printer and installed it again but got the same result.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Can you post the crash logs here? Just pick the newest crash log for each app. They should be in `~/Library/Logs/CrashReporter/`

Comment: Force quitting Preview doesn't generate a crash log in that directory - checking through Terminal. Would you like to read the crash report that pops up? Thanks again.

Comment: I was out for the holidays too! Post what you have and I'll see if it indicates anything, or if we need to look elsewhere. No promises, though.

Comment: I just crashed Preview with cmd+p. The crash report exceeds the number of available characters here, so I put the text here: http://pastebin.com/Sw4Z5keQ

Comment: Ah. That's technically a hang and not a crash. The info there makes me think that Preview is stuck waiting for a response from a separate background process. I can't do much more for you on this issue; you should report this at http://bugreporter.apple.com/ .

Answer (score 1):

My Preview on Lion was crashing on Print. The stack in the crash log shows:

```
Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   jp.co.canon.bj.print.v710a.pde.QualityMedia 0x060b52ae CBJ_SetDispValue(BJPDEMainContext*) + 44
1   jp.co.canon.bj.print.v710a.pde.QualityMedia 0x060b4820 CBJ_QualityMediaPDEPluginFactory + 1064
2   com.apple.print.framework.Print.Private 0x0654f709 0x6537000 + 100105
```

I tried upgrading to the most recent drivers from Canon's MX850 page. No luck.

I opened "Get Info" from the Finder, with Preview selected, and saw I had set it to "Open in 32-bit mode". I unchecked that box. Now Preview prints again.

Comment: Mine is unchecked. I checked the 32-bit mode, tried and crashed. Back to unchecked mode and it's still crashing. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Found Canon's response to this bug on 10.7:
http://www.canon.co.uk/Images/Mac%20OS%20X%2010.7%20printer%20driver%20compatiblity%20issue%20and%20recovery%20procedure_tcm14-852700.pdf

I also found that they issued a new driver a few weeks ago, so everything is OK. Preview is rocking again!
http://software.canon-europe.com/

Thanks everyone.